# [sqlalchemy]SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
@classmethod
def get(cls, id=None, **kwarg):
    return con_sesison.query(cls).filter_by(or_(id=id, and_(**kwarg))).scalar()
```

theh I get the error:

> SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg

Comment: There is no question stated.

Answer (score 1):

By using `id=id` you are passing an `id` argument with the value equals to `id` variable. Instead you need to pass filter conditions to `or_` in format `field == value`.

Just replace `id=id` with `id==id`.

Answer (score 0):

`filter_by` is just a shorthand function to do equal comparison via keyword arguments. Instead almost always it is clearer to use `filter` which allows expressions:

```
exprs = [cls.k == v for k, v in kwarg.items]
con_session.query(cls).filter(or_(cls.id==id, and_(*exprs))).scalar()
```

The `filter_by` method is not very flexible but with the above you *should* be able to achieve the same (untested).

Comment: Thanks. I think I has found the reason.<code>or_(cls.id==id, and_(*exprs))</code> the 'id' is keyword argument, and the and_(*exprs) is non-keyword argument which can not after the keyword argument.

Comment: Yes but if you just add a `=` sign, but leave the `filter_by` you will get false results. Check the query executed.

Comment: yeah. That is another question.